# Renaming multiple files with complex numbered names

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, mv

I have 365 files named

```
MOD11A1.A2010001.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf
MOD11A1.A2010002.h24v06.006.2016025151748.hdf
MOD11A1.A2010003.h24v06.006.2016025163706.hdf
```

and I want to rename these files as:

```
modis1.hdf
modis2.hdf
modis3.hdf
```

I am using the `mv` command separately for each file to rename them.

How do I achieve this in one go?

Comment: Where are you getting the number in your renamed file from? Is it at the end of the `.A2010001.` part of the original filename? Is there a chance that any of these number strings will have duplicate values?

Comment: .A2010001... .A2010365 is for 1...365 files.

Comment: If the glob `MOD*.hdf` is not returning any results your filenames must not be in the format you've stated, or you're not in the directory containing the files.

Comment: The question Zanna asked is still not answered by OP and it is important as it will change the suggested answer. The question I have is whether the number 1 to 365 in .A2010001...A2010365 must be used in the new file name. If so, the suggested answer below will not suffice.

Comment: Those aren't [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), just plain old integers!

Comment: @Zanna, No, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you only care about the `A2010...`  bit, using `rename` in the directory with the files:

```bsh
rename -n 's/.*A2010*(\d+).*/modis$1.hdf/' *
```

Example:

```bsh
$ rename -n 's/.*A2010*(\d+).*/modis$1.hdf/' *
rename(> MOD11A1.A2010001.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf, modis1.hdf)
rename(> MOD11A1.A2010002.h24v06.006.2016025151748.hdf, modis2.hdf)
rename(> MOD11A1.A2010003.h24v06.006.2016025163706.hdf, modis3.hdf)
rename(> MOD11A1.A2010365.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf, modis365.hdf)
```

Run without `-n` to actually rename the files.

Comment: How does the (\d+) capture the numbers? Is it regex magic?

Comment: @Arronical `\d` is any digit in Perl regex, the `()` is a capture group, and the preceding `0*` takes all the leading zeros

Comment: Marvellous, thanks for expanding my knowledge as always!

Comment: @Arronical `\d` simply is a shorthand for `[0-9]`, those shorthands are supported quite universally – for more see [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Comment: @dessert universally is a bit too broad, `sed` and `awk` don't, `grep` needs `-P` (for Perl-compatible RE)...

Comment: @muru The command worked fine with one set of files but when I am trying to do the same thing with another set of files using $ rename 's/.*A2006*(\d+).*/modis$1.hdf/' *  ==> it is renaming files as modis001, modis002, modis003.....

Comment: @VaishaliJain you forgot the `0` after 2006. It's supposed to be `20060*` With `2010`, the there already was a `0` at the end, so I didn't write out explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

The following way uses bash parameter expansion, but it does rely on your filenames being in exactly the format you've stated as it relies on the placement of the numeric string to be used. This isn't necessarily the most robust method. You must also be in the directory containing the files.

```bsh
for f in MOD*.hdf; do
  num="${f:13:3}"
  mv "$f" modis"$((10#$num))".hdf
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```bsh
for f in MOD*.hdf; do num="${f:13:3}"; mv "$f" modis"$((10#$num))".hdf ; done
```

This will move the files in the manner which you've asked for, meaning that `MOD11A1.A2010001.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf` will become `modis1.hdf`, `MOD11A1.A2010002.h24v06.006.2016025151748.hdf` becomes `modis2.hdf` etc.

Comment: Just noticed you removed the syntax highlighting on purpose – may I ask why? [The community's opinion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17449/507051) on this seems to be quite clear…

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `rename` command like this:

```
$ rename -n 's/MOD11A1\.A2010(...)\..*/modis$1.hdf/' MOD*.hdf
rename(MOD11A1.A2010001.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf, modis001.hdf)
rename(MOD11A1.A2010002.h24v06.006.2016025151748.hdf, modis002.hdf)
rename(MOD11A1.A2010003.h24v06.006.2016025163706.hdf, modis003.hdf)
```

After testing, remove `-n` to actually rename files.

#### Notes

- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `\.` literal `.`
- `...` three characters that could be anything
- `(some chars)` save `some chars` to reference later with `$1`
- We could use a simple regex to match the first part of the filename in the `rename` command, as muru's answer does. Sometimes you want to use a more explicit expression to distinguish between files that you do or don't want to act on, or to be sure that your regex won't suck up too many characters. There's usually a lot of flexibility in solving this kind of problem.

Note that this *doesn't* give you exactly what you asked for; it maintains the fixed width of the numbers. I have done this because it's a good idea to use fixed-width numbers in filenames (otherwise they will be sorted in a confusing way, with 10 before 2, for example) (and <del>because I haven't figured out how to use `rename` to create the names you actually asked for... if I do, I will update my answer</del> [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978743/527764) does that...).

Note that [Perl `rename` is not included in the default 17.10 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972836/rename-stopped-working-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-17-04-to-ubuntu-17-10), so if you are running 17.10 (or for future readers, perhaps a later version), start by running

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Answer (score 5):

The below code will do the following:

1. loop over all files which starts with `MOD` and ends with `.hdf`
2. Assign a variable, which will increase its value in 1 for every file
3. perform the `mv` command on the current file in the list and change its name to `modis` follows by the number from the variable, follows the the `.hdf`

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash 
   idx=1
   for file in MOD*.hdf
   do
       echo mv "$file" "modis$((idx++)).hdf"
   done
   ```

Note: the above script will only `echo` the command it plan to perform, you'll need to remove the `echo` from the `echo mv` line in order to perform the action action.

Sample output:

```bsh
mv MOD11A1.A2010001.h24v06.006.2016025150444.hdf modis1.hdf
mv MOD11A1.A2010002.h24v06.006.2016025151748.hdf modis2.hdf
mv MOD11A1.A2010003.h24v06.006.2016025163706.hdf modis3.hdf
```

Comment: mv: cannot stat ‘MOD*.hdf’: No such file or directory  error is showing in terminal.

Comment: how to use rename command for achieving my purpose?

Comment: @VaishaliJain - did you execute the above lines of code, in the folder which actually holds the MOD11A1... files?

Comment: @VaishaliJain - `mv` is a `rename command`

Comment: @pa4080 thanks for your comment! Will update my answer once I'll be near a computer.