# Swapping one character in filename with another

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, batch-rename

I have a file that has the name `a_b-c-d-e-f.txt`. I would like to take that current name and swap the dashes and underscores so that it becomes `a-b_c_d_e_f.txt`.

My intuition tells me to try `rename` or `tr`, but I'm having issues with this. Here is my current attempt

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt; do
  [ -f "$i" ] || break
  newFile=$(echo "$i" | tr '-' '_')
  cp "$i" $newFile
done
```

With this, I end up with

```
a_b_c_d_e_f.txt
```

It's that part between a-b that should not be changing. Also, that dash is not necessarily always in that place in the filename. For example, it may look like

```
a-b-c_d-e-f.txt
```

Or any combination like this. I want them to flip not matter their place in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for v in *.txt
do
    newname=`echo $v | tr '_-' '-_'`
    mv $v $newname
done
```

I found this to work. This was a combo of my post and Tony's response.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ echo "a-b_c" | tr '_-' '-_'
a_b-c
```

Comment: I ended up modifyng my code to look like     `for v in *.txt do
        newname=echo $v | tr '_-' '-_'
        mv $v $newname
    done`

Answer (score 6):

Some other options:

1. your loop but with sed's rarely used `y` transliteration command in place of `tr` ex.

   ```
   printf -v newFile "%s" "$(sed 'y/_-/-_/' <<<"$i")"
   ```
2. the perl-based `rename` command, using perl's built-in `tr` (no shell loop required)

   ```
   rename -n 'tr/_-/-_/' *[-_]*.txt
   ```

   (remove the `-n` when you are happy it's doing the right thing).

Comment: I get the following error with the -n flag: rename: invalid option -- 'n'

Usage:
 rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).

Comment: @GermanBarcenas that indicates that your system is using `rename.ul` as `rename` rather than the perl-based command that I mentioned. See [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

Comment: rename from util-linux 2.23.2. You are correct. How can I use the perl-based rename now that I know I'm using the wrong version? That link you posted indicates some command is not set up properly, but I'm unclear how to proceed. I've contacted my admin to see if they can help me.

Answer (score 4):

With [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) ([manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/prename.1p.html)) just

```sh
rename 'y/_-/-_/' *.txt
```

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) is more info about **`y/`**(transliteration). Also check [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641840/4970442) about `rename`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything at all. Is my rename the right rename? rename from util-linux 2.23.2

Comment: [Try `sudo apt install rename`](https://askubuntu.com/q/972836/349837). Test: `touch a_b-c-d-e-f.txt; rename 'y/_-/-_/' a_b-c-d-e-f.txt; ls a-b_c_d_e_f.txt`